# backbone.js - collection view giving "TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i've set up a jsBin of the issue here: http://jsbin.com/oSIJunu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

The Collection view isn't rendering due to an issue with the el property on the render function (friendView.render().el).

The view looks like this:

```
var FriendListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(friendModel){
        var friendView = new FriendView({model: friendModel});
        this.$el.append(friendView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Comment: the render method is not returning any value

Comment: I don't know backbone... but there is something seriously wrong here... because of the recursive calls

Comment: You need to return your FriendView object in `FriendView.render()` to allow for chainable calls. `return this;` should do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to return `this` from `render` function for chaining.

```
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
    },
```